# New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment in Azure CLI?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-cli, azure-managed-identity

Is there a pendant in the Azure CLI world for the following command?

```
New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $clientManagedIdentityObjectId -Id $serverAppRoleId -ResourceId $serverEnterpriseAppObjectId -PrincipalId $clientManagedIdentityObjectId
```

I'd like to add a managed identity to an `appRole` within an Enterprise Application.

[`az ad app permission add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app/permission?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-app-permission-add) does not seem to do the right thing or I am misinterpreting the underdocumented parameters.

Comment: `az ad app permission add` should do it as far as I can understand the documentation, but I only get `Updates to converged applications are not allowed in this version.` from it which is hard to understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no built-in cli command to do this, your option is to use [`az rest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az-rest) call the Microsoft Graph - [`Grant an appRoleAssignment to a service principal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) directly.

First, store a `.json` file as below to your powershell execute location, the meaning of the values see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request). e.g. my location is `PS C:\Users\joyw>`, I store the file in `C:\Users\joyw` folder.

```
{
  "principalId": "principalId-value",
  "resourceId": "resourceId-value",
  "appRoleId": "appRoleId-value"
}
```

Then run the command

```
az rest --method POST --uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{object-id of your Managed identity}/appRoleAssignments" --headers 'Content-Type=application/json' --body `@body.json
```

[image]