# Can I assign an app role access to a managed identity with Terraform?

Tags: azure-active-directory, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-managed-identity

It is possible to assign app role access for an app registration in terraform using `required_resource_access` for `azuread_application`. This will give access to a custom role to my API to another application/service principal.

I would like to do the same for a managed identity, but cannot figure a way to do that with terraform. It can be done with powershell like that e.g.:

```
New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $managedIdentityObjectId -Id $appRoleId -PrincipalId $managedIdentityObjectId -ResourceId $serverServicePrincipalObjectId
```

This call to graph api would achieve the same I think:

```
POST /servicePrincipals/{objectId}/appRoleAssignments
```

But I'd really love to do that with terraform if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such built-in resource in Terraform to achieve this, the only related thing here - [`azuread_application_app_role`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/application_app_role), if you want to do that, the workaround is to run the powershell command in Terraform manually via [`local-exec Provisioner`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. azuread_application_app_role is unfortunately only creating the role, not giving access to it. Do you know if there is some `az` command for that apart from doing `az rest` to grap api directly?

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik No, there's not, I have answered it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63593933/9455659

Comment: Thank, I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

There is a resource for this now and this works with managed identities. Just set the `principal_object_id` to the managed identities `principal_id`

```
resource "azuread_app_role_assignment" "example" {
  app_role_id         = azuread_service_principal.msgraph.app_role_ids["User.Read.All"]
  principal_object_id = azuread_service_principal.example.object_id
  resource_object_id  = azuread_service_principal.msgraph.object_id
}
```

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/app_role_assignment