# Use Azure Managed Identity to authenticate against App Service

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-logic-apps, azure-managed-identity, azure-appservice, azure-authentication

I have a .NET Azure App Service with Web API endpoints protected by `[Authorize]`, and a corresponding App Registration. This works fine and allows Azure AD user accounts to access the API.

Now I want to build a Logic App that accesses the Web API under its system-assigned Managed Identity, but this results in a 403 (Forbidden).

I have enabled the system-assigned Managed Identity for the Logic App, and in the authentication parameters of the HTTP connector, I entered the App Registration's resource ID (`api://<guid>`) in the "Audience" field.

What is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was missing.

1. I had to add an App Role to the app registration with "allowed member types" set to "Applications".
2. Then I added a service app role assignment with Azure Powershell:

```
Connect-AzureAD
New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -objectid {managed-identity-object-id} -principalid {managed-identity-object-id} -id {app-role-id} -resourceid {enterprise-application-object-id-of-app-service}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this with the Azure Portal or ARM Template?

Comment: Year 2024: REST API is another option. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63593933