# Enable access between two app or mutiple app services using Managed identity with out rotating token or credentials

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-managed-identity

Below is our architecture

1, Frontend  UI
2, Orchestrator Api ( .Net6 Api (App service)
3, Small Api's  (.net 6 appservice )

Frontend will only communicate with the Orchestrator Api , Orchestrator APi will communicate with more than 3 or 4 small api for specific data.

We are looking for a solution with managed identity for orchestrator api to talk to small api's with out exchanging token or credentials / any code change in the Api?

since there more apis joining , is it possible at the resource group level instead of setting at each APi level?

is there a way to do this ? please give some pointers or web reference?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: managed identities are managed service principals so they redeem tokens in order to get access to other resources.

Comment: you would need to create an app registration to authenticate to the "small api" then grant permissions to the managed identity (Orchestrator Api) to call the samll api..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67169780/how-to-explicitly-grant-access-from-a-user-managed-identity-to-a-aad-application

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70259377/use-azure-managed-identity-to-authenticate-against-app-service